# Issues with importing a library in nim test file

Tags: nim-lang

I'm having some issues including a library in a nim test file.

My code in my test file looks like this.

```
import unittest
import testToolpkg/Login
import dotenv
load()

test "valid login cookies":
  var cookies = loginCookies(os.get("EMAIL"), os.get("PASSWORD"), os.get("URL"))
  check cookies.len != 0
```

However when I run `nimble test` I get this error `Error: cannot open file: dotenv`. This seems to be an issue with any external library I try to use in a test.

The dotenv library works fine outside of the tests folder. I'm not sure if I'm missing some kind of option to get this to work? I am running this on windows as well.

Comment: What is `dotenv`?

Comment: Sorry, It's a library https://github.com/euantorano/dotenv.nim

Answer (score 3):

After adding the lib to my .nimble file

`requires "dotenv >= 2.0.0"`

The issue was resolved!